# Como usar autenticação em Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, autenticação, sinatra

Qual seria a melhor forma de se fazer autenticação em aplicações construídas com Ruby/Sinatra? Devise eu sei que não funciona. Já tentei vários tutoriais com Warden, mas as configurações são muito complexas e confusas ao meu ver. Autenticação simples com HTTP seria loucura. Qual então é a melhor maneira?

Comment: O que você usa como banco de dados?

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal estou usando MongoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente tem uma gem 'sinatra_warden' que faz a interface entre o warden e o sinatra para você https://github.com/jsmestad/sinatra_warden (em inglês). Exemplo de uso, da própria documentação do módulo:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra_warden'

class Application < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Warden

  get '/admin' do
    authorize!('/login') # require session, redirect to '/login' instead of work
    haml :admin
  end

  get '/dashboard' do
    authorize! # require a session for this action
    haml :dashboard
  end
end
```